# Why won't my divs align horizontally in Safari?

Tags: css, safari

Okay, so I'm currently using the following CSS to align two divs horizontally:

```css
#main #pnl1         { float:left; margin-right:10px; }
#main #pnl2         { float:left; padding-left:30px;}
```

Now, this may be a stupid question, but the above code works in both FF and Chrome... why not Safari? I tried added "display:inline-block" to them and added "float:right" to pnl2, but neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: This question requires more context.  What are the containing elements and their CSS style(s)?

Comment: Create a fiddle as jsfiddle.net demonstrating the problem and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the width of both div. That might be a problem.

Try this:

```
#main #pnl1{float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 49%;}
#main #pnl2{float: left; padding-left: 30px; width: 49%;}
```

Comment: This works! However, I have several elements in pnl2 that are also stacked horizontally. Is there any way to go about this instead of setting a width for every single element I wish to stack horizontally?

Comment: Then set #pnl1, #pnl2 display: table-cell;